# Обход массива в jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть некий html код, который записан в php, в который записываются данные из бд.
Для каждого нового $id создается новый .msg, таким образом на выходе имеем множестно таких блоков

```
<div class='msg new'  id='$id'>
        <div class='container col'>
          <div class='userData row'>
            <p id='num' name='id'>$id</p>
            <p id='ip'>$ip</p>
          </div>
          <div class='textArea col'>
           <p id='re'>Тема:$re</p>
            <p id='text'>$text</p>
          </div>
          <div class='btn-row row'>
            <div class='btn' id='done'>Выполенно</div>
            <div class='btn' id='cancel'>Удалить</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Так же есть 2 кнопки (#done, #cancel), на которых висят обработчики на jQuery.

```
  $("#cancel").click(function () {
  var id = $("p#num").html();
  $.ajax({
  url: "rm.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "text",
  data: {'c':'1', 'id': id},
  success: function() {
    alert("Cancel")
  }
  })
})
```

Нажимая, допустим, на #cancel, у меня обрабатывается только id первого msg, но мне нужно, что бы обрабатывался тот msg, где был произведен click.

Так проиходит выдача

```
<body>
      <div class="msg" id="201802240910">
            <div class="container col">
              <div class="userData row">
                <p id="num" name="id">201802240910</p>
                <p id="ip">192.168.1.4</p>
              </div>
              <div class="textArea col">
               <p id="re">Тема:Привет</p>
                <p id="text">234</p>
              </div>
              <div class="btn-row row">
                <div class="btn" id="done">Выполенно</div>
                <div class="btn" id="cancel">Удалить</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="msg" id="201802240906">
            <div class="container col">
              <div class="userData row">
                <p id="num" name="id">201802240906</p>
                <p id="ip">192.168.1.4</p>
              </div>
              <div class="textArea col">
               <p id="re">Тема:Проблема 5</p>
                <p id="text">йцу</p>
              </div>
              <div class="btn-row row">
                <div class="btn" id="done">Выполенно</div>
                <div class="btn" id="cancel">Удалить</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </body>
```

Comment: Все id элементов на странице должны быть разными.

Comment: id уникален для каждого msg

Comment: если это так, тогда в чем вопрос? `$("#cancel")` - селект для конкретного элемента ... если этот селектор приведен только как пример, то скорее всего нужно переформулировать вопрос, ибо выглядит как рабочий кусок (кроме того, что в php вроде как все же генерируются одинаковые id для кнопок).

Comment: Возможно, попробуйте `var id = $(this).closest('.msg').find('p#num').html();`

Comment: Я уточню. jQuery обрабатывает #cancel, но только в первом .msg, а их на странице несколько.  <div class="msg" id="201802240910">...</div> <div class="msg" id="201802240906">...</div>  и так далее

Comment: Id в data служит только для того, что бы php обработчик изменил строку в бд с этим id

Comment: Покажите как у вас генерируются эти блоки или вложите в пример кода хотя бы два таких блока, возможно у вас получается кривой html

Comment: Отредактировала ответ

Comment: Прочитайте, http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/id **Идентификатор в коде документа должен быть в единственном экземпляре, иными словами, встречаться только один раз.**

Comment: Просто заменить id на class...
Спасибо

Comment: В случае когда необходимы дублирующиеся идентификаторы можно использовать атрибут  name

Comment: @entithat неправда, идентификатор должен быть уникальным в поддереве, а не во всем документе.

Comment: @teran, хм. Я почему-то думал во всём. Спасибо за информацию:)

Comment: @teran как понимать «в поддереве, а не во всем документе»? Можно ссылку на разъяснение?